# How to run mp4 files if it is not working

Tags: python-3.8

I am trying to create a screen recorder in Python. I have created one which gives the output in
output.mp4 file. But when I opened the file, Windows says that the format is not readable. Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui 
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

resolution = (1920, 1080) 

codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID") 


fps = 60.0

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',0x7634706d , 20.0, (640,480))

cv2.namedWindow("Live", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) 

cv2.resizeWindow("Live", 480, 270) 


while True: 
    img = pyautogui.screenshot() 

    frame = np.array(img) 

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 


    out.write(frame) 

    cv2.imshow('Live', frame) 
  

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'): 
        break

out.release() 

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now can anyone tell me why is it not working and how to debug it? Thank you